Different Ghata Jatakas
I was just answering a question on Hindu.SE as to whether Ithihasas were copies of Jatakas. While looking for sources I found two Ghata Jatakas found on different sites.
WisLib Ghata Jataka
Sacred Text Ghata Jataka
Why two Jatakas after the same name?

Both Jataka (Ja 355 and Ja 454) are about when the Bodhisatta was named 'Ghata'.

The Master, having ended his lesson, identified the Birth: “At that time Ananda was king Vanka, and I myself was king Ghata.”
Ja 355


When the Master had ended this discourse, he said, “Lay Brother, thus people have got free from grief for a son by attending to the words of wise men of old; do not you think about it.” Then he declared the Truths (at the conclusion of the Truths the Lay Brother was established in the fruit of the First Path), and identified the Birth: “At that time, Ananda was Rohineyya, Sariputta was Vasudeva, the followers of the Buddha were the other persons, and I myself was Ghatapandita.”
Ja 454


More context, please.

The content is sufficient.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you for your answer.
